# Datatables (jQuery plugin) doesn't work on my jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatable, portlet

I want to include [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) in my portlet which works already fine without datatables. 
I tried several times to add it in my *JSP* page but it doesn't work. I get as output a normal html table.
So what's wrong with it? Can anyone help me?

Here's my jsp page:

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="org.quartz.JobDetail" %>
<%@ page import="org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl" %>
<%@ page import="org.quartz.Trigger" %>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#dataTable").dataTable();
  });
</script>

<portlet:defineObjects/>

<table border="1" id="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Job Name</th>
    <th>Job Group</th>
    <th>Job Builder</th>
    <th>Job Class</th>
    <th>Job DataMap</th>
    <th>Job Triggers</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  <c:forEach items="${jobsList}" var="aJob">
    <tr>
      <td>${aJob.getKey().getName()}</td>
      <td>${aJob.getGroup()}</td>
      <td>${aJob.getJobBuilder()}</td>
      <td>${aJob.getJobClass()}</td>
      <td>${aJob.getJobDataMap()}</td>
      <c:forEach items="${triggerlist}" var="trigger">
        <td>${trigger.getNextFireTime()}</td>
      </c:forEach>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console logs?

Comment: No, I'm having just some warns:  WARN  | Cannot find servlet context module [o.e.portal.resource.MainResourceResolver<ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]>] . Does it affect ?

Comment: I'm having also this info:  INFO  | At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Comment: Actually I'm talking about the client side logs. Check out if all libraries are loaded with some dev tool such as Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: I've checked some libraries and I don't think that I have such dev tools. Should I import hem to my project?

Comment: No libraries needed, just a web browser I suppose you already have, right? Check [Chrome Dev Tools for Chrome Browser](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) or [Firebug for Firefox Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/).

Comment: Ah ok, I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Could you check which line it is? Which function is undefined? You can click on left side source file in the error line to jump to instruction.

Comment: Here's the error:  $('#dataTable').DataTable();

Comment: The error ain't match your JSP page. You stated `$("#dataTable").dataTable();` in the main OP and ` $('#dataTable').DataTable();` in the error: note the **uppercase D** in function name.

Comment: Hi, thank you for editing my question. I tried your code but I'm still getting the same error.